# Find shapes on white background. Thinning the lines

Tags: opencv, contour, emgucv, canny-operator, adaptive-threshold

I have the following image as a test image:

[image]

I attempt to find the shapes on the image (and other images). My approch right now is the following:

1. Gaussian blur with a 3x3 kernel
2. Canny edge detection using
   list (to get all shapes)
3. Morphology with MorphOp.Close to close
   the edges
4. FindContours to find contours
5. Iteration of each contour:

   6. Find ApproxPolyDP
   7. Find ConvexHull
   8. Discard if
      hull size < 2, approx area < 200 or hull size > 50000, or arclength
      of the approx < 100
   9. Draw convexhull

This method yields the following images where the convex hulls are drawn:
[image]

This is almost perfect, but notice that the lines are seen as a contours events->suppliers and events->documents). When looking at the edge information, it becomes apparent why this is so:

[image]

The lines are detected as a contour. How could I prepare/find the shapes so the lines are not detected? I though of some thinning algorithm, but since I also work on real life images it is difficult to find a threshold that works. Here is an example of a real life image where thinning is difficult to do because thinning typically requires the images to be monochrome in black and white.

[image]

How would you do it? Is there some method to determine if the contour/convex hull is a line, rectangle or something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a mix of overlapping test and convexity scan. The convexity scans for the error between the convex hull and the actual contour. If this error exceeds a certain amount, the hull is ignored. The overlapping simply use bitwise and to detech if two convex hull's overlap. If they overlap more than 95% percent, one of them is ignored.